# Dynamic height UITableViewCell flickering

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have an issue with a dynamic height UITableViewCell flickering when scrolling back to the top.

I've set the value for `.estimatedRowHeight` and `.rowHeight` is `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

The constraints I have are shown on the following images:

[image: Image bottom constraint is >= 12]

[image: Subtitle label bottom constraint is also >= 12]

The subtitle label can have between 1 and 20 lines. With the constraints I do get what I want – layout itself looks great. When I scroll to end of my TableView – everything is OK, but, when I start to scroll back up – UI is flickering.

What could be the issue and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution, I hope it will help:-

```
 var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 100.0
 }
```

Comment: Appreciate your try to help! Unfortunately this doesn't fix the flickering when scrolling back to the top.